# Popup and ComboBox binding with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, combobox, telerik, popup

I have a problem regarding the comportment my ComboBox.
First I use a combobox to display all elements in a IEnumarale.
Then, with a button wich open a popup, the user can add an alement to that list.
The problem is that when the user validate his choice and close the popup, the element is not automatly added to the ComboBox without doing a refresh of the page.

The combobox is coded as follows :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="MyElements"
                        SelectionChanged="MyElements_OnSelectionChanged" 
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxElementsTemplate}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListElements}"/>
```

The constructor of the list is :

```
    public IEnumerable<Element> ListElements
    {
        get { return _listElements; }

        set
        {
            _listElements= value;
            RaisePropertyChange("ListElements");
        }
    }
```

And the code behind of the button to validate the user choice in the popup :

```
private ObservableCollection<HistoriqueElement> elementList = null;

private void SelectClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element= _GridList.SelectedItem as HistoriquePasserelle;
        if (_GridList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var installation = this.DataContext as Installation;
            if (installation != null && element!= null)
            {
                element.DateFin = DateTime.Now;
                HistoriqueElement newElement= new HistoriqueElement()
                {
                    Installation = installation,
                    ContactAction = GlobalActeurs.Current.CurrentContact,
                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                    Element = element.Element,
                    StatutElement = element.StatutElement ,
                    Owner= element.Owner,
                };
                elementList.Remove(element);
            }
            MainPage.ClosePopup();
        }
    }
```

When the user choose a new element in the list display in the popup and validate his choice, he returns to the main page, but his choice is not automatically added to the combobox.

I can post you any parts of the code.
Thank you in advance.

The method OnDataContextChanged :

```
public override void OnDataContextChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is Installation)
        {
            if (MainPage.CurrentInstallation.LastElements != null) 
            {
                ListElements = MainPage.CurrentInstallation.LastElements;
                MyElements.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                LoadOperation<Element> operation =
                    _context.Load(_context.GetCurrentElementsByInstallationId(MainPage.CurrentInstallation.Id));
                this._busy.IsBusy = true;
                operation.Completed += delegate
                {
                    this._busy.IsBusy = false;
                    if (operation.ManageError())
                    {
                        ListElements = operation.Entities;

                    }
                };
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        else
        {
            RaisePageTitleChanged();
            if (MainPage.CurrentInstallation == null)
                return;
        }
        if (MyElements.SelectedItem == null && MyElements.Items.Any())
        {
            MyElements.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the collection the ItemsSource is bound to implement INotifyCollection changed, that is, it's an ObservableCollection<>, then the combobox will be notified of any changes to the collection and you will not need to rebind or refresh, it will all be automatic.

Comment: I implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged. But it seems not to work because I had to click on an other page and go back to see the new element in the combobox.

Comment: Could you show the part of the code where you are populating the ListElements property?

Comment: I post in the question the code of the method when the context change.

Comment: Are MainPage.CurrentInstallation.LastElements and operation.Entities both ObservableCollections? That is what I meant by "implements INotifyCollection changed".

Comment: MainPage.CurrentInstallation.LastElements and operation.Entities are IEnumerable<Element>. Do I need to change to ObservableCollections ?

Comment: I would definitely suggest you try that.

Comment: But to be clear, neither LastElements or .Entitites are actually IEnumerable<Element> . IEnumerable is just an interface, which means that these variables are instances of a class which implements the IEnumerable interface. If you debug and go to the watch window, you will see which concrete class they are instances of. As long as THAT class implements INotifyCollectionChanged, your combobox will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the item to the list, bind the itemsource to the combobox, then you dont have to refersh.

```
MyElements.ItemsSource = ListElements
```

Comment: But I already bind my combobox with the itemsSource in the xaml. Do I need to do it again in the code behind ? In the constructor ?

Comment: That is not necessary if the ListElements is an ObservableCollection. Also, the code above would break the binding.